# Original value being updated by injector in test

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm attempting to test one of my injectable components. I'm using a provider to give it a mock value of `APP_CONFIG`. This is what the component looks like:

```
export let APP_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<any>('app.config');

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {

   private readonly config;

   constructor(private injector: Injector) {
      this.config = this.injector.get(APP_CONFIG);
   }


   public update(): void {
      this.config.context = 'some value'
   }

   public get config(): any {
     return this.config
   }
}
```

And this is what the test setup looks like:

```
const CONFIG = { context: 'cat' };

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            ConfigService,
            { provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: CONFIG },
        ]
    });

    service = TestBed.inject(AppConfigService);
});
```

The problem I'm having is that when `this.config = 'some value'` occurs in the update method it updates the original reference in the `CONFIG` object in my test. This is causing problems in my test because I can't properly check to see if `this.config` has changed because it's always equal to `CONFIG`.

For example:

```
it('provides updated config after update', () => {
   const result: any = service.config;
   // CONFIG is currently {context: 'cat'}
   service.update();
   // Once service.update() occurs CONFIG gets changed to {context: 'some value'} and the following test fails as a result. I expect it to pass because result should be different from the original reference.
   expect(result).not.toEqual(CONFIG);
})
```

As a result this is causing any other subsequent tests that import the `CONFIG` object for comparison reasons to fail for the same reason.

Is there something I can do to prevent this regression? This started occurring after upgrading from Angular 8 to 9 so I'm not sure if there was some changes under the hood that were made that alters how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are just passing around the same reference and comparing it to itself. You'll need to clone the original object.

The easiest way imo is to use the spread operator:

```
{ provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: ...CONFIG },
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the spread operator here ?

Comment: @CCBet the spread operator effectively clones the object being spread.